# Unable to locate package python-pip on live system

Tags: apt, software-installation, python

I am trying to install electrum on my Ubuntu live USB. Please forgive me because I am very new to this OS. I have also made a persistence 4GB space for installing software.

How can I get past this error? I tried using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

first, but I still get

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

when I try to install.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two Methods:

- You can install through Ubuntu Software Center.

  1. Open Ubuntu Software Center and search for `easy_install`

     [image]
  2. Highlight alternative Python package installer (python-pip) from the
     list and click Install

     [image]
  3. You can check weather the installation was successful or not by
     giving the command

     `which pip`

     you will see the path of installed application, for example

     `/usr/local/bin/pip`
- Second method

  1. Open terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+T and type the following:

     `cd ~`

     to navigate to your home directory.
  2. Then issue the below command:

     `wget -P Downloads/ https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/oodt/tools/oodtsite.publisher/trunk/distribute_setup.py`
  3. Next step is to run the downloaded script. To do this, issue this
     command:

     `sudo python Downloads/distribute_setup.py`
  4. and type your user password when prompted (Please, note that your
     account needs to be a member of Administrators group in order to
     issue `sudo`).
  5. Hit `Enter` and let the script run.
  6. To ensure easy_install is installed, issue the command below:

     `which easy_install`

     The typical response in case the installation completed successfully
     would look something like this:

     `/usr/local/bin/easy_install`
  7. The next thing to do is use easy_install to install pip. For that
     you’ll need to issue:

     `sudo easy_install pip`
  8. Enter your password if prompted to confirm command.
  9. Let the installer run and once the installation is completed type:

     `which pip`

     This command should typically respond with something like this:

     `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: Hello I tried typing 'easy_install' but no result returned :(

Comment: I also tried searching the exact words alternative python and python-pip also doesn't return any result.

Comment: It says "Interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)" is installed

Comment: python interpreter 2.7 and 3.2 also installed

Comment: I mean they have check marks on the icons

Comment: I was following this installation instruction from electrum page: http://electrum.org/download.html

I started typing installation for python-qt4 and for python-pip but the error above showed up after I entered it

Comment: from the terminal:

Comment: Python 2.7.3
GCC 4.7.2 on linux2

Comment: I have exited the shell. Thanks for sticking up for me for so long.. 

WHat do you mean by "find the same on my edited answer"? I tried refreshing the page but no edited answer

Comment: Hi I get an error:

wget: missing URL

Comment: All done! wohoo you are a GOD send! let me just install electrum to see if it will work out now

Comment: Electrum is fully working. Will the installed application be able to load again if I reload the OS on usb?

Comment: I tried click upvote but it says I need more reps
I clicked the check button to mark it as my answer. Is that alright?

Also can you tell me if the those I have installed won't be erased when I finsihed using the usb pen (That is pulling the pen stick out of my machine). Will it still retain the apps?

Comment: Yes. you have now installed the application successfully. so there should not be any issues. you are all set.

Comment: Please be very careful about downloading scripts via HTTP (and not HTTPS) and then running them with sudo. This puts your system at extreme risk. It is trivial for a network-controlling attacker to alter data in transit and install malware on your machine using man-in-the-middle techniques (for example using ARP poisoning). Especially if you plan on storing bitcoin on your machine with electrum as you mentioned, you should be very cautious about how you download software. Please make sure you download your software using HTTPS from trusted domain names.

Comment: @Daytron try turning on Universe repository.  The `python-pip` package is in Universe, and if it can't find it you need to verify that 'universe' repository is enabled.

Answer (score 8):

I, too, am new to Ubuntu, and I had a similar problem. I needed to install pip, but kept getting the error message:

> Unable to locate package python-pip

After doing more research, I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This seemed to do the trick for me. I hope this helps others having the same issue.