# sudo apt-get install python-pip is failing

Tags: 14.04, python, pip

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

how to install python-pip in ubuntu:14.04?

Comment: Here have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/268539/unable-to-locate-package-python-pip which could help you.

Comment: you probably forgot to run `sudo apt-get update` first

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`python-pip` is in the universe repositories, therefore use the steps below:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository universe
Error :  sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found

Comment: @Ravi_SS sorry, forgot the installation of `apt-add-repository`. Install with `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common` as described now in my answer. Start again with the first command.

Comment: apt-get update is working fine, but sudo apt-get update is giving me error.. And also sudo apt-get install software-properties-common is not working.

Comment: On sudo apt-get install software-properties-common                                          Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libroken18-heimdal amd64 1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Comment: Are you online?

Comment: i am online yes

Comment: Try to ping the host `ping -c3 archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: ping -c3 archive.ubuntu.com
ping: unknown host archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: Four your system your are not online.

Comment: i was able to install python. apt-get install python

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean`, now install python again and test it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`

Comment: apt-get install --reinstall python
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 134 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python amd64 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 [134 kB]
Fetched 134 kB in 0s (604 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 14423 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python_2.7.5-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python (2.7.5-5ubuntu3) over (2.7.5-5ubuntu3) ...
Setting up python (2.7.5-5ubuntu3) ...

Comment: What can I say, it is the same server. `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu `

Comment: Try it again with `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: @Ravi_SS nice to hear, that your problem is solved, but sorry. I can't answer new questions in comments. But on AskUbuntu are many answers for the question about sources.list and sources.list.d ;)

Comment: These instructions work on the Linux Subsystem for Windows as well.

Comment: I'm a Dockerfile with base image ubuntu:latest (20.04). When building the image I run `apt-get update -y`, and in the next line `apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential`. I'm seeing the error "E: Unable to locate package python-pip" and I don't know why. Does anybody here know why?

Comment: unfortunately didn't work in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: With Ubuntu 20.04 I replaced ```sudo apt-get install python-pip``` with ```sudo apt-get install python3-pip``` it works properly

Comment: Failed for ubuntu kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 21):

I ran into this problem trying to install pip for python2; e.i. I wanted pip2. What worked for me was this:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me.